# Default c++ compiler version

Tags: macos, terminal, development

I need to compile some small cpp files so I'd like to do that through the terminal. I'm using Catalina 10.15.5. I found out that macOS has a built-in clang compiler and I can use commands like `c++` or `g++`. It's version:

```
Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

But I need to know which c++ version it uses (e.g. c++17, c++11 or even less version). It's really important for my files.

I know I can specify the version like `c++ --std=gnu++17` but the question is how to make the compiler to use it by default (without aliases, there must be a command to change it). Or at least how to find out which version does it use right now?

Comment: The simplest command for a single file, e.g. foo.cpp is: ```clang++ -Wall -std=c++17 foo.cpp -o foo```. For many .cpp files, a small makefile will be enough.

Comment: @Yoan my purpose is to run several files during my exam to show that they at least compile. And I'm not allowed to write the next one before I finished the previous. So using the terminal is much easier and faster)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the default version by looking in the manual:

```
man clang
```

It states:

> The default C++ language standard is gnu++14.

This is basically the same as C++14, but with some GNU specific extensions.

The way to change the default setting when used "standalone" (i.e. without an Xcode project, Makefile or similar) is actually to make a shell alias. There's no `clang` configuration file where you can change the default - you'll need to recompile the compiler to change it.

Comment: And a makefile or an xcode project is much better than an alias for this. I would start with an xcode project